# How to implement DbContext Pooling without dependency injection in .NET 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, pool

DbContext Pooling without dependency injection was introduced in EF Core 6.0. I am using .NET 5 which does not support EF Core 6.0, so how can we achieve Pooling without dependency injection in .NET 5?

Entity framework core Pooling

```
var factory = new PooledDbContextFactory<PooledBloggingContext>(options);
```

[DbContext pooling EF6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=without-di%2Cwith-constant#tabpanel_1_without-di)

Comment: Updated the Question.i am talking about DbContext pooling

Comment: Third question about pooling. Why do you need that?

Comment: .NET 5 is no longer supported.